# The system cannot find the file specified, Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

Error:(20, 0) CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

[image]

Gradle is not syncing the project "GnuCash" form "github"

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get github dependency in you project. First you have to specify the repository in build.gradle and then add that dependency in you project.

What you can do for git repository

Step 1. Add the JitPack repository to your build file Add it in your build.gradle at the end of repositories:

https://jitpack.io

```
repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Step 2. Add the dependency in the form

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
}
```

Comment: Still same error , i m not getting github dependency in my project . I just downloaded a zip file from gihub and want to open it android studio. but gradle is not syncing.
You should have a look at image link i attached

Comment: Here is a link for GnuCash app and error in my android studio log 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQKbY.png
https://github.com/codinguser/gnucash-android

Comment: @YousufAwan I am Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It looks like you are not  able to build github project GnuCash. Please correct me if I am wrong. I would recommend you to build your project using command line first with the steps provided in https://github.com/codinguser/gnucash-android#building.

Comment: bro thats for Mac , and i am using windows... i want to open it with android studio which is pretty simple often but not working today don't know why